# Monic epimorphisms in topological spaces category

Tags: general-topology, continuity, category-theory

Do you have an example of a continuous map $f\colon A\to B$ between topological spaces, such that $f$ is bijective and its inverse is not continuous?

I remark that the category must be that of topological spaces, not of haussdorf or compact ones.

Comment: discrete to indiscrete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A$ as $\mathbb R$ endowed with the discrete topology, $B$ as $\mathbb R$ endowed with the usual topology, and $f$ as the identity map.

Comment: Let $A$ be a closed subset of the reals with the euclidean topology. The same $A$ is open in the reals endowed with discrete topology. Since the identity map fails to be continuous, the identity itself is a counterexample of non isomorphic monic epimorphism. Is it correct?

Comment: The map that I described is an example of a monic epimorphism which is not an isomorphism.